Where is the boundary for creating a table with types in the database?
I have a model with QR codes that has a field called type. This field can have two values: 1 (Plate) or 2 (Sticker). I could simply create an enumeration of these types as an array in the model and just refer to the index whenever I need to get the name of that type. In my situation, is it necessary to create a separate table in the database for these types, considering that they are unlikely to be expanded? I would also like to understand when it is appropriate to store these states or types in the database.
At the moment, I have a table in the database for storing these two types, and I'm increasingly leaning towards hardcoding them inside the model.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79026241/where-is-the-boundary-for-creating-a-table-with-types-in-the-database

@WebDev Thanks for linking this issue in this issue

This question has no right or wrong answer and thus is opinionated. I would just define the extra table in DB, its probably less work than asking a SO question in my opinion. Data integrity is more important than saving a couple of calories.

If the values for the type field (Plate and Sticker) are static and unlikely to change, hardcoding them in your model as an enumeration is more practical than creating a separate table. This approach keeps things simple and avoids unnecessary database lookups.
You’d only need a separate table if:

The values might expand or change over time.
You require translations or additional data related to these types.
In your case, since expansion is unlikely, hardcoding seems the better option.

